# Splitting responsibilities of mappers on Elastic MapReduce (MySQL + MongoDB input)

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-streaming, elastic-map-reduce

I want to make sure I understand EMR correctly. I'm wondering - does what I'm talking about make any sense with EMR / Hadoop?

I currently have a recommendation engine on my app that examines data stored in both MySQL and MongoDB (both on separate EC2 instances) and as a result can suggest content to users. This has worked fine, but now I we're at a point where it is now taking longer to execute the script than the intervals in which it should be running. This is obviously a problem.

I'm considering moving this script to EMR. I understand that I will be able to connect to MongoDB and MySQL from my mapping script (i.e. it doesn't *need* to be a file on S3). What I'm wondering is - if I start examining the data on MySQL / S3 - does Hadoop have some method of making sure that the script doesn't examine the same records on each instance? Do I understand the concept of Hadoop at all even? Sorry if this question is really noob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, hadoop does make sure that the input records from DB are split and then only passed to mappers, i.e. same records will not be read by different mappers (even though they are run on same instance).

Speaking generally, task of splitting data is upto the chosen `InputFormat`, to quote from [here](http://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/module5.html):

> Another important job of the InputFormat is to divide the input data
>   sources (e.g., input files) into fragments that make up the inputs to
>   individual map tasks. These fragments are called "splits" and are
>   encapsulated in instances of the InputSplit interface. Most files, for
>   example, are split up on the boundaries of the underlying blocks in
>   HDFS, and are represented by instances of the FileInputSplit class.
>   Other files may be unsplittable, depending on application-specific
>   data. Dividing up other data sources (e.g., tables from a database)
>   into splits would be performed in a different, application-specific
>   fashion. When dividing the data into input splits, it is important
>   that this process be quick and cheap. The data itself should not need
>   to be accessed to perform this process (as it is all done by a single
>   machine at the start of the MapReduce job).

You might have already read [this](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2009/03/database-access-with-hadoop/), but this is a nice initial resource on DBInputFormat for hadoop.

Comment: Great answer, thanks. Would you recommend using something like Sqoop or should I connect to the database directly from my PHP script?

Comment: If your database's size is big enough (50GB+), then I would recommend going for Sqoop, also Sqoop is good when you need to run hadoop jobs periodically on incremental database. Even if your DB isn't big enough, using Sqoop gives you better control over updating data.